# How to get property out of image object

Tags: php

Very new to php. i have the following var_dump($largeImage) that has the below output.

I'm trying to get the thumbnail url.

I have tried

```
$tempLargeImage = $largeImage["url"];
$overlayImage = $tempLargeImage["thumbnail"];
```

But this i get " Illegal string offset 'thumbnail' in"

```
    array(10) { 
["id"]=> int(440) ["alt"]=> string(0) "" ["title"]=> string(40) "bcd8d0b4d2d97f1889d7fab5d82075d07bfb51e8" ["caption"]=> string(0) "" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["mime_type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["url"]=> string(112) "http://a.com/.jpg" ["width"]=> int(1589) ["height"]=> int(2048) ["sizes"]=> array(48) 
{ ["thumbnail"]=> string(120) "http://a.com/-150x150.jpg" ["thumbnail-width"]=> int(150) ["thumbnail-height"]=> int(150) ["medium"]=> string(120) "http://a.com/-233x300.jpg" ["medium-width"]=> int(233) ["medium-height"]=> int(300) ["medium_large"]=> string(112) "http://a.com/.jpg" ["medium_large-width"]=> int(1589) ["medium_large-height"]=> int(2048) ["large"]=> string(121) "http://a.com/-795x1024.jpg" ["large-width"]=> int(795) ["large-height"]=> int(1024) ["portfolio-square"]=> string(120) "http://a.com/-570x570.jpg" ["portfolio-square-width"]=> int(570) ["portfolio-square-height"]=> int(570) ["portfolio-portrait"]=> string(120) "http://a.com/-600x800.jpg" ["portfolio-portrait-width"]=> int(600) ["portfolio-portrait-height"]=> int(800) ["portfolio-landscape"]=> string(120) "http://a.com/-800x600.jpg" ["portfolio-landscape-width"]=> int(800) ["portfolio-landscape-height"]=> int(600) ["menu-featured-post"]=> string(120) "http://a.com/-345x198.jpg" ["menu-featured-post-width"]=> int(345) ["menu-featured-post-height"]=> int(198) ["qode-carousel_slider"]=> string(120) "http://a.com/-400x260.jpg" ["qode-carousel_slider-width"]=> int(400) ["qode-carousel_slider-height"]=> int(260) ["portfolio_slider"]=> string(120) "http://a.com/-500x380.jpg" ["portfolio_slider-width"]=> int(500) ["portfolio_slider-height"]=> int(380) ["portfolio_masonry_regular"]=> string(120) "http://a.com/-500x500.jpg" ["portfolio_masonry_regular-width"]=> int(500) ["portfolio_masonry_regular-height"]=> int(500) ["portfolio_masonry_wide"]=> string(121) "http://a.com/-1000x500.jpg" ["portfolio_masonry_wide-width"]=> int(1000) ["portfolio_masonry_wide-height"]=> int(500) ["portfolio_masonry_tall"]=> string(121) "http://a.com/-500x1000.jpg" ["portfolio_masonry_tall-width"]=> int(500) ["portfolio_masonry_tall-height"]=> int(1000) ["portfolio_masonry_large"]=> string(122) "http://a.com/-1000x1000.jpg" ["portfolio_masonry_large-width"]=> int(1000) ["portfolio_masonry_large-height"]=> int(1000) ["portfolio_masonry_with_space"]=> string(120) "http://a.com/-700x902.jpg" ["portfolio_masonry_with_space-width"]=> int(700) ["portfolio_masonry_with_space-height"]=> int(902) ["latest_post_boxes"]=> string(120) "http://a.com/-539x303.jpg" ["latest_post_boxes-width"]=> int(539) ["latest_post_boxes-height"]=> int(303) } 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you have two array the second array is nested within the first

you must get the image url from the `sizes` array not from first array directly

```
$overlayImage = $tempLargeImage["sizes"]["thumbnail"];
```